# foreach in int[] without explicit declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, foreach, instance

I would like to do use a foreach loop, that runs along a int[] array, but without instance the array in a particular variable. For example, I want to:

```
int x[3] = {1,2,3};
for (int &i : x) std::cout << i << ' ';
```

But without instance x. I have tried this:

```
for (int &i : {1,2,3}) std::cout << i << ' ';
```

But this does not compile.

Comment: seems to work fine here: http://tpcg.io/NoEWvj

Comment: The second example compiled and ran on my machine.  Are you sure you have your compiler set to C++17?

Comment: @Eljay I was able to compile it in C++14 and C++11.

Comment: It compiles fine in C++11 and later for me. Please include the actual error message.

Comment: If you solved the problem, post that as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove &

```
for (int i : {1,2,3}) std::cout << i << ' ';
```

Because, if `i` is modified inside the loop, it would be a problem...

Comment: This is caused by the fact that `{1, 2, 3}` is a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), which has iterators to `const` elements, so you can't bind a non-const reference to that. Using `const int&` would have worked too (not that it would be any better than simply `int`).